# VBA Change value in textbox based on whether other textboxes are empty

Tags: vba, excel, textbox, is-empty

Struggling with some code here, looking for help. I am trying to figure out the correct syntax for updating a textbox value based on whether another textbox has a value or not.

Breakdown

- Textbox1 name = arisk_box
- Textbox2 name =  adjust_box3
- Textbox3 name = rr_box

This is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub arisk_box_Change()
If arisk_box.Text <> "" And adjust_box3.Text = "" Then
    rr_box.Value = arisk_box.Value
 ElseIf arisk_box.Text <> "" And adjust_box3.Text <> "" Then
    rr_box.Value = adjust_box3.Value
 End If
 End Sub

   *If arisk_box has a *VALUE* and adjust_box3 *DOES NOT* then rr_box = the value from arisk_box
  Elseif arisk_box AND adjust_box3 both have a *VALUE* then rr_box = the value from adjust_box3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way it to use 2 separate macros, one for each textbox change event. But it may not work as smoothly as you want it to. I sure someone will have a more advance method.

```
Private Sub adjust_box3_Change()
    If arisk_box <> "" And adjust_box3 = "" Then rr_box = arisk_box
End Sub

Private Sub arisk_box_Change()
    If arisk_box <> "" And adjust_box3 <> "" Then rr_box = adjust_box3
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi GMalc, Thanks for the response but this didn't work. I am trying to move the same code under something else to see if it simply isn't doing anything because if the location.

Comment: The code was tested and performed per your request. How did it not work? Did you put the subs in the UserForm? (The subs must be part of the UserForm to work). If the subs are in the UserForm, did you actually change the value in either of the text boxes?

Comment: Hi GMalc, The first line of the code works but the rest doesn't. The code is in the userform under the Subs of the textboxes just as you have written above. To clarify, the arisk_box always gets filled in and it get's filled in first. The adjust_box3 is a variable, meaning, it sometimes will be filled in or not and it will always be filled in "second" to arisk_box. So when the arisk_box gets filled in the rr_box gets filled in but when I fill in the adjust_box3 with a string rr_box doesn't update itself to the string in adjust_box3. It still stays on arisk_box. Does that help more?

Comment: To clarify... if arisk_box = true and adjust_box3 = False Then rr_box = arisk_Box --- Else if arisk_box = true and adjust_box3 = True Then rr_box = adjust_box3.  What if arisk_box is updated when adjst_box is already filled in?

Comment: Sorry about the misunderstanding, i think my update is what you want.

Comment: Hi GMalc, Yes! that's the logic exactly. rr_box still should take the value of adjust_box regardless if arisk_box is updated or not. If adjust_box =true then rr_box - adjust_box. If I needed to start over with an updated arisk_box I have a clear button to do that. The flow of the form  moves from arisk_box to adjust_box(with conditions). So going back up the flow doesn't make sense and I would simply clear the form if I needed to do that. I will try your update and let you know. Thanks for helping :)